# Named Stuctured Data storage in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing an application that calculates various Pandas dataframes over various time periods.   Each of these Dataframes have additional data that need to be stored with them.

I can quite easily define a structure using lists or dicts to carry the data, but it would be nice if it is nicely structured.

I have looked at (tried namedtuples).   This is great as it simplifies the syntax when accessing the information a lot.   Problems with tuples are of course that they are immutable.

Have gotten around this by either doing all the calcs ahead of time and living with not being able to change them (without jumping through few hoops) or by following code:

```
from collections import namedtuple
m = namedtuple("Month", 'df StartDate EndDate DaysInMonth
m.Month = 2
m.df = pandas.DataFrame()
etc....
```

this seems to work, but I am actually misusing the named tuple class.   m in the above code is actually a "type"  not an instance.   Although it is working and I can now assign to it I am probably going to run into some problems later on.

```
type(m)
>>> type
```

Any suggestions on whether I could carry on with this structure or if i should rather create my own class for the data structure?

Comment: "simplifies the syntax", that's what i normally say about `OrderedDicts` (or mainly traditional dict's). What's most important is that you're comfortable working with your data sets, we could go on with what we think is the best but at the end you're the one who will be working and should understand the code/syntax. If you're asking us which has the best performance? Then it's another question entirely. (this was just a small side-note) :)

Comment: Actually I am actually trying to understand why the code that I wrote is working.   I am able to assign to m and read back from it.  Just have a nasty suspicion that even though it works now it is going to back and bite me if i do not clean it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing setting m.Month to 2 is using something all classes can do because they walk and talk like dictionaries.

```
class Month():
    pass

a = Month()
a.df = 2
```

This works without doing anything special. If you look inside a's **_*dict*_** attribute

```
print(a.__dict__)
```

You'll see something like the following

```
{'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, 'df': 2}
```

I would probably use the empty class instead of the namedtuple if you want to change the values at a later time. All the namedtuple machinery in the background get you nothing for your use case.

Comment: Absolutely correct.   Could actually add the metadata directly to my pandas dataframe.  there are possibilities that some of the methods might clobber it though so I settled on wrapping my dataframe in a class and adding the attributes to that.